# Animation with Data Joins d3

Tags: animation, d3.js

I'm trying to animate a data join. I can get the state to change and update but there isn't any seamless animation between states.

I tried to refer to this to answer my question:
[d3.js trying to animate data, but changed data always treated as new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690793/d3-js-trying-to-animate-data-but-changed-data-always-treated-as-new)

This data is created upon json load...and then, on a button click, i'm just simply adding 20 ( for testing purposes ) to my y values...it updates but there is no transition. What am i selecting incorrectly?

The variable bar is already defined globally.

```
function btnClick(){
        //bar.exit().remove();

            bar = chart.selectAll("g")

            .data(mydata.players)
            console.log(bar.data(mydata.players))
            bar.exit().remove()


            bar.enter().append("g")
            .transition()
            .duration(1650)
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ",0)";
            });

        bar.append("rect")

            .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.money+20)
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return height - y(d.money+20);
            })
```

Trying to move the transition before the height change:

```
     chart.selectAll("g")
.data(mydata.players);
 bar.exit().remove();

bar.attr("transform",
function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ",0)";
});

bar.append("rect")
.attr('width', x.rangeBand())
.transition()
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.money + 20)
})
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.money + 20);
})
```

I think i'm just not grabbing the right selection for bar in btnClick(). Maybe I'm not supposed to grab all the 'g' elements? And the bar is defined on json load earlier so I'm not certain I should even have to define it again by selecting all the g elements....if it's already been built. I have stored it and should be able to manipulate it: but if I don't define it, then for some reason the exit.remove() doesn't work.

Comment: You are doing the transition on the enter selection...you can simply move it to the update selection, before the height is changed. Also, you don't need an enter selection for your update. Just select the element(s) again and change the attribute.

Comment: That doesn't quite work. I think it's because i'm appending new rect instead of using the current ones?

Comment: Yes, do not append a new rect...just do `bar.attr(...`. If you continue to have issues, create a fiddle to make it easier to investigate.

Comment: Yes. I've tried this...unfortunately, there just isn't even a change in bar height at all if I remove that line. No update on click. For some reason, it needs the new rectangles.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtR4V/

Comment: Put json as object in javascript here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtR4V/1/

Comment: :) In the meantime, I was cooking up a minimal example for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rM3LT/). I need to scoot off, but I will take a look at this later tonight if you or someone else does not solve it. But please do take a look at the example I linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made the small necessary changes to your code to have this working. So, two things to note:

1. you want to select your rectangles for update:

   ```
   bar.select("rect")
       .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
       .transition().duration(750).ease("linear")
       .attr("y", function (d) {
           return y(d.money + 20)
       })
       .attr("height", function (d) {
           return height - y(d.money + 20);
       })
   ```
2. you want to re-set your y domain to accommodate for the new data values (you really don't have a new set of data, you are just adding 20...so, do the same here):

   ```
   y.domain([0, d3.max(mydata.players, function (d) {
       return d.money + 20;
   })])
   ```

NOTE: your tallest bar will not move since its value puts it at the top of the old and new scales (the domain is based on the data values). To see all bars rise, you can inflate the domain of your original data (say, + 20). I placed a comment where you can do this.

Here is the complete [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T3DNx/1/).